# Find all references of a dependency using maven or artifactory?

Tags: maven, artifactory

Let's say I have an internal library called superlibary.jar that is being stored in our local artifactory repo, and used by other in house applications ( also stored in artifactory).  How can I use maven or the artifactory search feature to find all references to that jar?

I know about the maven dependency plugin which can be used to build a dependency tree.  But this seems only be useful for determining the dependencies for the current app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the search functionality in Artifactory to find all the references of this JAR.
Since this is a Maven package you can do it with the quick search or maven package on the gavc cordinates.

Refer to this Doc: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Application+Search